# JsonPath: Parsing JSON into a Java object with List member

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I am trying to parse the following JSON into Book class:

```
{
  "inventory": {
      "book": {
          "title": "Database Systems",
           "authors": [
              {"name": "Sudarshan"},
              {"name": "Korth"},
              {"name": "Silberschatz"}
           ]
       }
  }
}
```

Book class which has JSON annotations for the fields and has the following definition:

```
package com.example.books    

public class Book {

    @JsonProperty("title")
    private String title;

    @JsonProperty("authors")
    private List<Author> authors;

    public Book() {
        authors = new ArrayList<Author>();
    }
    // constructors, getters, setters

}     

public class Author {
    @JsonProperty
    private String name;

    // constructor, getters, setters...

}
```

I am trying to achieve this using `com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath`:

```
Book book = JsonPath.read(inventoryJson.toString(), "$.inventory.book");
```

This results in the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.example.books.Book
```

I have also tried:

```
Book book = JsonPath.parse(inventoryJson.toString()).read("$.inventory.book", Book.class);
```

This one now gives a different exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can not find Array 'authors' field in class com.example.book.Book
    at net.minidev.json.writer.BeansMapper$Bean.startArray(BeansMapper.java:79)
    at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserBase.readMain(JSONParserBase.java:402)
    at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserBase.readObject(JSONParserBase.java:542)
    at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserBase.readFirst(JSONParserBase.java:297)
    at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserBase.parse(JSONParserBase.java:154)
    at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParserString.parse(JSONParserString.java:58)
    at net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:263)
    at net.minidev.json.JSONValue.parse(JSONValue.java:206)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.mapper.JsonSmartMappingProvider.map(JsonSmartMappingProvider.java:82)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.convert(JsonContext.java:192)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.read(JsonContext.java:158)
```

How do I make it work?

Original classes:
    http://pastebin.com/SAhipfxL
    http://pastebin.com/vWfWsaqN
    http://pastebin.com/7tqhJfw3

Complete stack trace:
    http://pastebin.com/QWV89Hgj

Answer (score 0):

I found series of mistakes in code from your question.

Let's start from json itself: it is not well-formed in exactly that view, which you've provided.

It should be:

```
{
"inventory": {
    "books": {
        "title": "Database Systems",
        "authors": [
            {"name": "Sudarshan"},
            {"name": "Korth"},
            {"name": "Silberschatz"}
         ]
     }
 }
}
```

Notice also please, that it should be "**books**" instead of "**book**".

Next problem is that you've declared classes `Book`and `Author` as package local. This won't work. Consider making them `public` or  `public static` at least.

These fixes will solve your problem, for second statement:

`Book book = JsonPath.parse(inventoryJson.toString()).read("$.inventory.books", Book.class);` - it should work properly.

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes. I just created these dummy classes to imitate the original classes I have and point out the exceptions received. I have edited the question with corrections and it still does not work.

Comment: 1) You didn't fix `JSON`. 2) It is not clear, did you declare classes as top-classes or not? 3) It **should** work - I've tested with my fixes.

Comment: Added pastebin links for the code, along with complete exception stacktrace. It still has "books" as key (forgot to change that).

Comment: *books*, not *book*, do you see the difference?

Comment: Pastebin links are in accordance with "books". Am I missing something here?

Comment: Ok, now I see, but it is better to fix it in code inside question it self.

Comment: Try to change `Book book = JsonPath.parse(inventoryJson.toString()).read("$.inventory.books", Book.class);` to `Book book = JsonPath.parse(testJsonString).read("$.inventory.books", Book.class);`